# C# DirectX Circle Drawing not working correctly

Tags: c#, directx

I've been trying to recode a C++ DirectX code to C# that would help me with Drawing a perfect circle. Currently I have this code that i translated by myself:

```
 private void Circle(int X, int Y, int radius, int numSides, Color color)
    {

        Vector2[] Line = new Vector2[128];
        float Step = (float)(Math.PI * 2.0 / numSides);
        int Count = 0;
        for (float a = 0; a < Math.PI * 2.0; a += Step)
        {

            float X1 = (float)(radius * Math.Cos(a) + X);
            float Y1 = (float)(radius * Math.Sin(a) + Y);
            float X2 = (float)(radius * Math.Cos(a + Step) + X);
            float Y2 = (float)(radius * Math.Sin(a + Step) + Y);
            Line[Count].X = X1;
            Line[Count].Y = Y1;
            Line[Count + 1].X = X2;
            Line[Count + 1].Y = Y2;
            Count += 2;
        }
        line.Begin();
        line.Draw(Line, color);
        line.End();               
    }
```

The problem is that the circle is drawn but also a Line from a point in the circle to the left top corner, like this.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that if you want a circle, you should tell Direct2D. I.e. use [`ID2D1EllipseGeometry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371239(v=vs.85).aspx). On hardware that supports ellipse primitives (i.e. most any kind of modern graphics hardware), that should be much more efficient than drawing your own circle line-segment by line-segment.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or at least details like what type the variable `line` has, it's hard to say for sure how to fix the code you have. Probably you need a `MoveTo()` call before you start drawing the individual lines. But really, you should just draw a circle with a circle primitive.

Answer (score 1):

Don't iterate with a floating point variable. They might get imprecise during the iteration. In your case, the last step is probably very close behind the upper bound (instead of hitting it exactly). So it won't get calculated and left as the default `(0, 0)`.

So use an integer iteration variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numSides; ++i)
{
    float a = i * Step;
    ...
}
```

Then, you can also get rid of `Count`.

Furthermore, you should make your coordinate buffer dynamic:

```
Vector2[] Line = new Vector2[2 * numSides];
```